# Create 2 new columns from a query

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I am battling with joins and inner joins.

I have 2 tables that look like this:

USERS

```
-----------------------------------------
ID | fname | lname | div_1_id | div_2_id
-----------------------------------------
1    paul    smith     1         2
2    john    lip       2        null
3    kim     long      1         4
```

DIVISIONS

```
------------------
ID | name
------------------
1    estate
2    litigation
3    property
4    civil
```

DESIRED RESULT (sql query)

```
--------------------------------------------------
user.ID | fname | lname | div_1_name | div_2_name
--------------------------------------------------
  1        paul    smith     estate       litigation
  2        john    lip       litigation   
  3        kim     long      estate       civil
```

I would like to create a new table from a MS sql query that looks like the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `LEFT JOIN` for this:

```
SELECT u.ID, u.fname, u.lname
      , d1.name as div_1_name
      , d2.name as div_2_name 
FROM USERS u 
LEFT JOIN DIVISIONS d1 ON u.div_1_id = d1.ID 
LEFT JOIN DIVISIONS d2 ON u.div_2_id = d2.ID
```

#### [See this SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7ec01/1)

Comment: This worked well for me. It produced exactly what i required. thank you well much

Comment: I'm happy to know it helped. Please mark this post as answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try using sub-query:

```
select a.ID, a.fname, a.lname,
    (select name from DIVISIONS b where b.id=a.div_1_id) div_1_name,
    (select name from DIVISIONS b where b.id=a.div_2_id) div_2_name
from 
USERS a
```

Comment: Will subquery make it run slow?

Comment: [Join Vs SubQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577174/join-vs-subquery) - 
"In most cases JOINs are faster than sub-queries and it is very rare for a sub-query to be faster."

Answer (score 0):

Use `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT Users.ID, Users.fname, Users.lname, Divisions.name,Div.name
FROM Users INNER JOIN Divisions ON Users.div_id_1 = Divisions.ID
INNER JOIN Divisions Div ON Users.div_id_1 = Div.ID -- Second join with Divisions Table with Alias.
```

Comment: the INNER JOIN will eliminate the one that has the null value particularly the 2nd row in his/her example.